# Can't get DBLIB PDO setup on mac to connect to MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, pdo

I am trying to connect to an external mssql database from my local dev environment on Mac El Capitan.  I notice in my php info that I do not have dblib setup in my pdo.  I have mysql, odbc, sqlite.  I have been looking all around to see how to get this installed and pretty much everything I have seen says to use Freetds to accomplish this.  I did a brew install Freetds and it says "freetds-0.95.69 already installed".  So that tells me I already have it.  I am wondering if there are more steps that I am missing such as putting something in my php.ini file to get this working.

I also saw another suggestion to turn on mssql_secure_connection = On in my php.ini which I did but that did not help.

Any additional suggestions would be appreciated.

I am using a connection like this and it works when I upload it to my server which has the appropriate drivers installed.

```
$DBH = new PDO( "dblib:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass );
```

Comment: I have found this https://github.com/BellevueCollege/public-docs/blob/master/PHP/configure-mssql-pdodblib-mac.md and followed instructions but when I try to copy the .so files I get operation not permitted.  This is because rootless of El Capitan.  I don't want to disable it.  Is there another local place I can copy .so files so php.ini will read them?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I have to compile the build for the .so files using the correct php-config.  I got 2 installs of php and I was building them with default from osx which was not matching what I was running so they were being ignored.

Comment: This one gave me a nightmare, hit me up if you run into problems. i spent 2 weeks on this and the worst part is that after getting connections working dblib doesnt support ouput parameters from  a stored procedure mh!! MSSQL :( and linux is complete mayhem